# SwiftUI List can not have animation if data source contains enum type

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

Currently I'm using SwiftUI `List` to display a list of item which is `enum` type. The expected behaviour is to have the animation when update new data to the list. I can not achieve it if using `List` , but it can work fine if using `LazyVStack`  or changing the data source item to class object(UserCellViewModel). For my app, I have to use List, and the animation base on the datasource changes, not from tapping on the buttons.
Please let know if there is anything that I need to change when using `List` to have the animation the same as `LazyVStack` . Many Thanks!

```
class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum CellType: Identifiable, Equatable {
        case test1
        case test2
        case cell(viewModel: UserCellViewModel)
        
        var id: String {
            switch self {
            case .test1, .test2:
                return "\(self)"
            case .cell(let vm):
                return vm.id
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Published var users: [CellType] = []

    func add() {
        users = [UserCellViewModel(user: User(name: "Paul")),
                 UserCellViewModel(user: User(name: "Taylor")),
                 UserCellViewModel(user: User(name: "Adele")),
                 UserCellViewModel(user: User(name: "Test"))]
                    .map({ CellType.cell(viewModel: $0) })
        count = users.count
    }
    
    func remove() {
        users = [UserCellViewModel(user: User(name: "Paul")),
                 UserCellViewModel(user: User(name: "Test"))]
                    .map({ CellType.cell(viewModel: $0) })
        count = users.count
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Add") {
                viewModel.add()
            }
            Button("Delete") {
                viewModel.remove()
            }
            List(viewModel.users) { user in
                switch user {
                case let .cell(viewModel: vm):
                    UserCellView(viewModel: vm)
                default: EmptyView()
                }

            }
            .listStyle(.plain)

            // If replacing List by LazyVStack, it works properly.
//            ScrollView {
//                LazyVStack {
//                    ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
//                        switch user {
//                        case let .cell(viewModel: vm):
//                            UserCellView(viewModel: vm)
//                        default: EmptyView()
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//
//            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .animation(.default, value: viewModel.users)
        
    }
```

Comment: Why not animate the change in the view model?